# How parent frame access child frame window?

Tags: javascript, iframe, ecmascript-5

**In the below code:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">    
      </head>
      <body>

        <iframe srcdoc="<script>
                            window.innerStr='xyz';
                        </script>" >
        </iframe>

        <script>

            function test() {
                let iframe = window.frames[0];
                console.log('frames innerStr: ' + iframe.innerStr); // does not work if child frame says innerStr = 'xyz' without window scope
            }
            window.onload = test;  
            test();
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

For `window.innerStr='xyz';`, without using `window` scope in child frame, parent frame could not access child frame property(`innerStr`)

Is window scoping mandatory for JS coding? `window.open('file.html')` has similar results.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow

Comment: `iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument` if Same Origin Policy requirements are met.

Comment: @zer00ne None of them has `innerStr` property. `document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentDocument;` . yes same origin

Comment: lose `window`, `iframe` is already the window.

Comment: Not sure what is the question here. Is it *Do I need to attach my variable to the frame's `window` object to access it from the parent frame*? Yes, and no... You can also attach it to the `document` property, since the iframe will also expose it, but since `document` is actually just a property of `window`, it comes to the same at the end. Now, you can transmit the data from one frame to the other by using *postMessage*, but it will be copied and not direct accessed like through the global scope (except for transferables, which could be transferred but that's an other topic).

Comment: @Kaiido why  `window` object need to be attached to a variable? To access in parent frame

Comment: `window` is not attached to a variable, but you need to attach your variables to `window` because that's the only thing the `<iframe>` will leak from the frame's context. That's no different than other scoping. You need to attach your objects as properties of an other object which you can access in order to access this scoped object.

Comment: @Kaiido saying `let x=2` in JS file,  does not attach x to window?

Comment: no `let` and `const` don't attach to the global scope

Comment: @Kaiido `var x=2` is not attach ing to window object

Comment: Yes it does https://jsfiddle.net/3thz8a38/

Comment: @Kaiido you are right. Now, why would I need postmessage()?

Comment: In case of cross-domain documents, the `<iframe>` won't let you access its framed `window` object. So in this case the only way is to use `postMessage` which, as I said, will copy the data being transmitted (i.e will not work for complex objects like DOM Element or alike, and the changes made to these objects in one frame won't reflect in the other one)

Comment: @Kaiido In case of cross-domain documents, does `window.open(url)` let you access it's `window` object?

Comment: No you would have to use messaging.

Comment: No for same domain, Window object `window.open` returns is like the ìframe.contentWindow` one, and will leak the same details, on the same conditions.

Comment: how do you access the DOM in the frame?!

Answer (score 0):

You can use messages to talk from the parent to the iframe.

Put this code in the parent

```
// Create IE + others compatible event handler
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

// Listen to message from child window
eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
    // e.data = "foo"
    doStuff(e.data);
},false);

function doStuff(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

Put this code in the iframe

```
var someVarible = "foo"
parent.postMessage(someVarible, "https://urlofsite.com");
```

**EDIT**
To get it work with the code that you already have.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<iframe srcdoc="<script>let innerStr='xyz';window.parent.test(innerStr);</script>">
</iframe>

<script>

    function test(foo) {
        var iframe = window.frames[0];
        console.log('frames innerStr: ' + foo)
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **1)** Does the same logic work for `window.open('local url')`? to access window scope of new window` from old window? **2)** How come, child document can talk to parent document using `window.parent`, but parent document cannot talk to child document?

Comment: Yes you can use window.open('url'). If you want to talk to the iframe you would use var foo = window.open('url'); then use foo.postMessage("bar").

You can read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: Can't I use global symbol registry? Instead of posting messages?

Comment: I don't know enough about Symbol() for me to give you a proper response after reading about it, I've edited my answer to get it to work with your current code

Comment: Oops... you are are sending message from child frame to parent frame? `parent.postMessage`

Comment: Note that this will copy the value being posted, it won't be the sameobject (while with a string it doesn't really matter, it might for objects)